# How to customize user feedback in Sentry?

Tags: sentry

How does one customize the user feedback form in Sentry?

By default is says something along the lines of "It looks like we're having some internal issues."

Is it possible to change the message, data collected, etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an API [here](https://docs.sentry.io/api/projects/post-project-user-reports/), but you have to get an `event_id` which is basically generated by an error or an exception in you app... I'm still trying to figure out how use this functionality without the default integrated form.

Answer (score 2):

Sentry has a built-in front-end user feedback form which you can trigger and customize to some extent. A basic implementation in Angular4+ might look like this:

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { Config } from '../config/config';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'https://0123456789abcdef.sentry.io/000001', 
  release: Config.SENTRY_RELEASE
});

export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error: any): void {
    const eventId = Sentry.captureException(error.originalError || error);
    Sentry.showReportDialog({
      eventId,
      title: 'Aw, Snap! You broke the internet!',
      subtitle: 'Send us an email and we will fix it.',
      subtitle2: 'Please refresh your cache to continue (cmd+R / ctrl+R)'
    });
  }
}
```

[Here's a link to the showReportDialog API](https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/user-feedback/?platform=javascript)

Comment: You can also turn off Sentry branding in the Dashboard `https://sentry.io/settings/[YOUR_TEAM]/projects/[YOUR_PROJECT]/user-feedback/`

Comment: Does it support in mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

It seems the current way is this:

- make your own UI
- generate and enqueue a Sentry event (it's OK if the even has not been sent yet)
- POST to the special endpoint that Sentry's report collector uses

The details are described in https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/3111

```js
const dsn = SENTRY_DSN;
const eventId = captureMessage("User report");

const query = Object.entries({dsn, eventId})
  .map(([k, v]) => `${ k }=${ encodeURIComponent(v) }`).join("&");

const body = new FormData();
Object.entries(
  {name: "Alex Foo", email: "a.foo@example.com", comments: "Long text goes here"})
  .map(([k, v]) => body.append(k, v));

fetch(`https://sentry.io/api/embed/error-page/?${ query }`,
  {method: "POST", body});
```